# Make native query in standalone Waterline

Tags: express, sails.js, waterline

When trying to use Waterline standalone mode, I could not find the correct method to perform native queries. With Sails.JS the sendNativeQuery method is used which I could not find in the instances of the models. Does anyone know how I can perform these queries?

Thank you!

---

I have the same problem, i think it sail who set getDatastore() and sendNativeQuery() function on model and datastore.

Surely on this file: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-hook-orm/blob/master/lib/build-registered-datastore-instance.js
and the function is defined here: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-hook-orm/blob/master/lib/build-registered-datastore-instance.js

Im going to implement this in my code but if someone have a better idea or have already doing this i appreciate help :)

Answer (score 0):

Sails enables you to access what called `datastore.manager`

> Depending on the adapter, this might represent a connection pool, a single connection, or even just a reference to a pre-configured client library instance.

If you are using MongoDB for example, you can have a raw Mongo collection instance.

see [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/datastores/manager).

Comment: Yes! but, the problem is that I'm not using Sails.js, I'm just using Waterline + Express and the models I created do not have the way to make native queries. Thank you!